# Why sinon.assert.match(actual, expected) would throw AssertError when both actual and expected are identical string values?

Tags: javascript, sinon

I have `mocha, chai and sinon` Javascript testing framework and library are availabe on an application I inherited. I am new to all ^ of them and I've been reading their `APIs` to learn how to use them properly.

Here is Javascript object I want to validate. If expected `name` property is missing, validator would throw `UsageError: name property is missing`.

```
// person object
const person = { name: 'peter' }

// validate method of exported validator JS component
async validate(person) {
    const { name } = person;
    const promises = [];
    if (typeof name !== object) { throw new UsageError('name property is missing'); }
    ...
    else { promises.push(fooService(name)); }
    try {
        await Promise.all(promises);
    } catch (error) { throw (error); }
}

// unit test in sinon
describe('Validate person', async function() {    
it('should throw error not find name property', async function() {
  const person = { 'foo': '1234 somewhere' };
 try {
  await validator.validate(person);
 } catch(error) {      
  sinon.assert.match(error, 'name property is missing');
 }              
});
```

This is `async + await` code so little I know `sinon` would be a fit then when I executed the unit test, I am even puzzled with following error msg:

```
AssertError: expected value to match
expected = UsageError: name property is missing
actual = UsageError: name property is missing
```

Both `actual` and `expected` come out same in string I think but I don't understand why I got `AssertError`. I'd appreciate if someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong and guide me the right way to implement this unit test. Ty!

[update]

My apology, I realized that I gave a wrong example within the sample test I have posted. I corrected it by having `person object does not contain name property`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is failed because the test compares the reference. The code creates new reference by using `new` statement e.g `new UsageError`.

An example:

```js
let expect = require('chai').expect;

it('checks equality' ,function() {
  const actual = new Error('name property is missing');
  const expected = new Error('name property is missing');

  expect(actual).to.equal(expected);
})
```

The code above will give output

```
// output
AssertionError: expected [Error: name property is missing] to equal [Error: name property is missing]
      + expected - actual
```

The solution maybe you could compare the message by accessing `message` property

```
it('checks equality' ,function() {
  ...

  expect(actual.message).to.equal(expected.message);
})
```

Hope it helps